# Not able to populate pojo with RestAPI Data

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, android-bootstrap

I am using android-bootsrap from this link for my project from
    https://github.com/AndroidBootstrap/android-bootstrap

I retained the project structure as it is and not performing authentication. In my apps i am making a call to a rest API which is returning the data in Json format. Using retrofit we are calling the services and getting the data in Json also.

We have created one POJO class for Json API. But in my app we are unable to get the Pojo object populated with Rest API data.

My code look as follows:
**User.java**

```
public class User implements Serializable {
 private String shortDescription;
 private String name;

 public String getShortDescription() { return shortDescription;}
 public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
    this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
 }

 public String getName() { return name; }
 public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
 public interface UserService {
   @GET("/search/items")
   UsersWrapper getUsers();
 }
```

**UserWrapper.java**

```
public class UsersWrapper {
 private User results;
 public User getResults() { return results; }
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
 String data = "";
 private User user;
 @Inject protected BootstrapServiceProvider serviceProvider;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new MyTask().execute();
 }

// making async request 
 class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            user = serviceProvider.getService().getUsers();   
            user.getShortDescription();   // here i am getting NullPointerException
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

I am getting the data in the retrofit log but when i am trying to get data through User object i am getting NullPointerException.

My Json data is as follows:

{"name":"user1","short_description":"user1 is a postgraduate student"}

Comment: Can you please add an example of what the JSON result from your API looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way you have your User/UserWrapper class setup GSON is expecting a JSON result that looks like:

```
{
  "results": {
    "name": "user1",
    "short_description": "user1 is a postgraduate student"
  }
}
```

If the JSON Result is just the stuff inside of the "results" block in my above example you would want to ditch the UserWrapper all together, and change your Service Interface to look like:

```
public interface UserService {
   @GET("/search/items")
   User getUsers();
}
```

If the JSON Result is an Array of Users such as

```
[
  {
    "name": "user1",
    "short_description": "user1 is a postgraduate student"
  },
  ...
]
```

Then you would want your Interface to look like:

```
public interface UserService {
   @GET("/search/items")
   List<User> getUsers();
}
```

Comment: if i drop UsersWrapper class then, I need to write implementation of getUsers() in User class.

Comment: I tried out your approach , but still i am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Thanks @Pedlar. Finally i got the output i didn't notice about results object.